# clickhouse, retrieve data from already running query

Tags: sql, clickhouse

So I need to know is there any way to get data from already running query.
Had some large identical query that run different people in almost same time and each take few min to execute. Are there a solution that people can just do smth like **select where query_id ='id_of_slow_query'** and wait till running query in process list execute and retrieve it's data?

Comment: Not really.  But you might be able to save the results of the slow query in a table and make that available.  Materialized views can often be used for this process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will show you query id, elapsed time, #written rows, memory usage, etc. of the last 5 queries that are already running:

```
select * from system.processes limit 5
```

I hope this answers your question, if not, please specify what kind of 'data' from the running query you want to see.

Comment: I need to receive data from already running query from processlist. For example i run query select * from some.table and then find it in processlist and retrieve data from already running query.

Comment: If by _data_, you mean the _response_ to that query, I'm afraid it's not possible. But you can get to know some statistics regarding that query using the `system.processes` table.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, to my knowledge, there is no clickhouse feature that allow you to get the result of previous query without re-run them.

However as Gordon Linoff said, you can store the result in a temporary table  and identify the queries that come up often with a unique id.

If the query that come often are always a narrow of a bigger table you can use a materialized view.
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view